# Subtract data frame rows if there have same main column name

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have two data frames that looks something like this:

```
df1 =

col1      col2      col3      col4
-----------------------------------
100       456.8     986.4     100.4
200       547.5     666.4     123.4
300       812.4     321.2     234.2
400       121.2     111.1     456.8


df2 = 

col1      col2      col3      col4
-----------------------------------
100       256.8     386.4     700.4
200       547.5     466.4     323.4
600       312.4     121.2     534.2
800       821.2     311.1     856.8
```

So as can be seen the first column, `col1`, which I call the main column have similar values in both data frames, but also different values.

What I would like to do is to get a result that looks something like:

```
df_final = 

col1      col2      col3      col4
-----------------------------------
100       200.0     600.0     600.0
200         0.0     200.0     200.0
300       812.4     321.2     234.2
400       121.2     111.1     456.8
600       312.4     121.2     534.2
800       821.2     311.1     856.8
```

So the ones where the main column `col1` are the same it will add those, and subtract the values in the other columns, and if there are no match the row will just stay as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the unique indices among `df1`, and `df2` and create a list out of it (you can use `np.ravel` to get a 1D list of all the indices then use `np.unique` to get only the unique index values), pass it to `reindex` for both the dataframes then substract them filling `NaN` by zero, and take the absolute value:

```py
>>> allindex = np.unique(np.ravel([df1.index, df2.index]))
>>> (df1.reindex(allindex).fillna(0)-df2.reindex(allindex).fillna(0)).abs()
       col2   col3   col4
col1                     
100   200.0  600.0  600.0
200     0.0  200.0  200.0
300   812.4  321.2  234.2
400   121.2  111.1  456.8
600   312.4  121.2  534.2
800   821.2  311.1  856.8
```

In case if you get error from `np.ravel` due to different number indices in the two dataframes, you can either convert indices to the list then add the two lists and get unique out of it `allindex = np.unique(df1.index.to_list() + df2.index.to_list())` or you can use `np.concatenate` to concatenate the indices then get the unique `allindex = np.unique(np.concatenate([df1.index, df2.index]))`

Comment: Ah, I seem to get an `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`. Maybe I should have mentioned that the data frames are not necessarily the same length. They have the same number of columns, but rows can differ.

Comment: I don't think above solution depends on number of rows, because when you do `reindex`, all the indices appear in both the dataframes, so the number of rows will ultimately match before subtracting the values. That's the sole purpose above to have the same number of rows with identical indices in both the dataframes. Make sure `col1` is the index column in both the dataframes as you have shown in the question. Try `df1.set_index('col1', iniplace=True)` and `df2.set_index('col1', iniplace=True)`, before running above code.

Comment: I think it is the `np.ravel` thing that makes it not work. If I do something like `x = np.array([1, 2, 3]); y = np.array([4, 5, 6]); print(np.unique(np.ravel([x, y])))` it works, but if I add e.g. another integer to `y` it doesn't work due to them not being the same size.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `np.ravel` expects the array to be of the same size. Then convert the index to list and add them: `allindex = np.unique(df1.index.to_list() + df2.index.to_list())` then pass it to `np.unique`. Or, you can also concatenate the index before passing it to `np.unique`: `np.unique(np.concatenate([df1.index, df2.index]))`

Answer (score 1):

Set 'col1' as index on df1/df2 and then perform the difference. Finally, merge the difference and the unused rows:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('col1')
df2 = df2.set_index('col1')
df3 = df1.sub(df2).dropna()
pd.concat([df3, df1.drop(df3.index), df2.drop(df3.index)]).reset_index()
```

output:

```
   col1   col2   col3   col4
0   100  200.0  600.0 -600.0
1   200    0.0  200.0 -200.0
2   300  812.4  321.2  234.2
3   400  121.2  111.1  456.8
4   600  312.4  121.2  534.2
5   800  821.2  311.1  856.8
```